# Ignite dataStreamer is not working

Tags: ignite

I am exploring Ignite dataStreamer with the following code.
But the output is:

For MessageKey0001, the output all displays data is null.
For MessageKey0003, the output also all displays data is null
For MessageKey0002, the output shows nothing, looks that receiver code is not run

When I change

```
dataStreamer.addData(i, "data-" + i);
```

to

```
    IgniteFuture future = dataStreamer.addData(i, "data-" + i);
    future.get();
```

The future.get() doesn't return, looks addData doesn't finish anyway?
I am not sure where the problem is, can someone take a look? Thanks!

```
package ignite.streamer;

import org.apache.ignite.*;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.annotations.QuerySqlField;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.stream.StreamReceiver;

import javax.cache.Cache;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

class IgniteDataStreamer_Person implements Serializable {
    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private String name;

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class IgniteDataStreamerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String configPath = "D:/Software/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/config/default-config.xml";
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(configPath);
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, String> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<Integer, String>();
        String cacheName = "stream_cache";
        cfg.setName(cacheName);
        cfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, IgniteDataStreamer_Person.class);
        Cache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);

        IgniteDataStreamer<Integer, String> dataStreamer = ignite.dataStreamer(cacheName);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            dataStreamer.addData(i, "data-" + i);
        }

        //null is got from cache
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("0001: data is %s ", cache.get(i)));
        }

        dataStreamer.receiver(new StreamReceiver<Integer, String>() {
            public void receive(IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache, Collection<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> entries) throws IgniteException {
                //nothing is printed to console
                for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : entries) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("0002: key is: %s, value is: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                }
            }
        });

        //null is got from cache
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("0003: data is %s ", cache.get(i)));
        }
        ignite.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataStreamer uses batches in order to provide good performance. You should flush data in your case (use `flush()` method) before block on `future.get()` method.

Please, see `IgniteDataStreamer` javadocs for details.

Comment: @Tom Note though that you should NOT call `dataStreamer.flush()` each time you add data. Data streamer will automatically flush the data as soon as it fills it's internal buffers. You can also use `dataStreamer#autoFlushFrequency` to enable background data flushing if you add data from some external source and there may be significant intervals between `addData` calls. Also note that DataStreamer is a closable resource and you should close it after you have added all the data. It will flush automatically on close.

Comment: I would also add that setting receiver after some data was already added doesn't make much sense. I actually believe that the exception should be thrown in this case.

Comment: Thanks all the guys(a_gura, Alexey, Valentin ) for the great answer. Now I understood.

Comment: Hi @ValentinKulichenko, I am also facing a similar problem. why there is no log getting printed in the receiver? can you please help

Comment: @lucid Have you tried the suggestions from this discussions. Tom had an issue because the code was incorrect, it's all described above.